# Implement SSL encryption in WCF

Tags: wcf-binding, wcf-security

What are the configuration changes required to use SSL in a WCF .svc file.Did  a  lot of googling over the same and have tried all possible ways by configuring endpoints and service behaviors but it ends up giving endpoint not found error or 404 error .Kindly suggest if i am missing out on any thing .Attached alongwith is the web.config file.Thanx in advance

Comment: The web.config file must have got lost along the way. Please recheck the question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the encryption, then [HTTP Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx) will be your solution.

Note that you will also need a SSL certificate provided by a trusted authority, such as VeriSign.